# bring the last 10 orders whitout repeating

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT a.id, a.fecha, a.ser, a.numero, c.nombre_apellido, a.estado, a.tipo, a.articulo, a.precio_asignado, a.retirada, a.pronta, a.precio, a.confirmada, d.marca, a.modelo, a.fecha_prometido, a.fecha_asignado, a.presupuesto, a.cant_llamados
FROM (
(
(
ordenes_servicio_bitacora b
LEFT JOIN ordenes_reparaciones a ON b.id_orden = a.id
)
LEFT JOIN clientes c ON a.cliente_id = c.id
)
LEFT JOIN marcas d ON a.marca_id = d.id
)
ORDER BY b.id_bitacora DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

and it brings me this 
[image]

as you see the id column of the order is repeated because of the cross with bitacora table i need not to be repeated, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to decide which other values to chose when they are different!

Comment: You're only using `bitacora` to order the rows but none of its column are in the output. I see you're using left joins but do you really need that table in the query?

Comment: You can use distinct, if all columns are repeated. if not we can think in different way

Comment: the theme was the bitacora is giving me the last consulted/changed rows that's why i order by id_bitacora desc, i just make a query on that with distinct and it's done!

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` should do the job in your case, as all the columns' data are repeated for the row not just the `id` column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.id, a.fecha, a.ser, a.numero, 
  c.nombre_apellido, a.estado, 
  a.tipo, a.articulo, a.precio_asignado, 
  a.retirada, a.pronta, a.precio, 
  a.confirmada, d.marca, a.modelo, 
  a.fecha_prometido, a.fecha_asignado, 
  a.presupuesto, a.cant_llamados
FROM ordenes_servicio_bitacora b
LEFT JOIN ordenes_reparaciones a ON b.id_orden   = a.id
LEFT JOIN clientes c             ON a.cliente_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN marcas d               ON a.marca_id   = d.id 
ORDER BY b.id_bitacora DESC   
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It's just the id column that's duplicated, not the other columns.

Comment: @jarlh - Not just the `id` all the columns are repeated for the row, so `distinct` should eliminate the whole duplicated row.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you're right, hard to know since the columns far right aren't visible.

Comment: is kind of wear i think distinct will do the job too, but i make a subquery and it's solved

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT a.id, a.fecha, a.ser, a.numero, c.nombre_apellido, a.estado, a.tipo, a.articulo, a.precio_asignado, a.retirada, a.pronta, a.precio, a.confirmada, d.marca, a.modelo, a.fecha_prometido, a.fecha_asignado, a.presupuesto, a.cant_llamados
FROM (
(
(
(SELECT DISTINCT id_orden
FROM  `ordenes_servicio_bitacora` 
ORDER BY id_bitacora DESC 
LIMIT 10) b
LEFT JOIN ordenes_reparaciones a ON b.id_orden = a.id
)
LEFT JOIN clientes c ON a.cliente_id = c.id
)
LEFT JOIN marcas d ON a.marca_id = d.id
)
```

i just made a subquery and the job is done, thanks by the answers and comments :)